# Locality Sensitive Hashing - meaning of a block

Tags: hash-function, data-mining

I'm reading [one of the early LSH papers](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring13/cos598C/Gionis.pdf) and I'm a little confused by the meaning of a "block". In particular, in the proof of theorem 1 in section 3.2 (p 522), what are the blocks being pointed to? Just hash buckets? The step I'm having trouble with is "The expected number of blocks allocated for $g_j$ which contain exclusively points from $P'$ does not exceed 2" - I'm having trouble parsing this sentence, even though the paper makes it sound trivial.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Can you give a page number? $\:$